# Is there a recommended integer type to store function pointers in standard C

Tags: c, c99, c11

The C99 standard has `uintptr_t`, a recommended integer type to convert data pointers (pointers to objects) to, but I did not find an equivalent integer type to store function pointers. Did I overlook it?

A specific compiler could define such a type even though it is not in the standard, but a compiler is more likely to state that a function pointer can be stored in (say) a `uint64_t` than to define a new type.

Another difference is that it can make sense to do integer arithmetic on a data pointer in ways that it doesn't on function pointer. One common idiom is `(int*)(((uintptr_t)p + 15) & ~(uintptr_t)15)` but there is no reason to apply this idiom to a function pointer.

Comment: I think all function pointer types have the same size, so you could use something like `void(*)()` as a placeholder...

Comment: "there is no reason to apply this idiom to a function pointer" That's probably the reason why such pointer is absent from the standard: it's easy to come up with reasons why to convert data pointers to integers; for function pointers it's not so easy - I cannot think of an operation that would require changing a function pointer in any way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight [one reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282032/converting-object-and-function-pointers-to-integers) why this may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no such recommended pointer type.

To *store* the pointer you may use any other function pointer type, as long as you don't call your function through it.

If you convert your pointer than back to the original type you may call your function. This is always guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. This was the last bit of fact-checking for a draft of a blog post. You have “won” the right to see it early and tell me everywhere I got the syntax for function pointer types wrong: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/08/24/Function-pointers-in-C (password: pointer)

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I am not a compiler (and most of the audience aren't here, I think) so I am not a reliable proofreader for C syntax, in the contrary. But besides that your post looks fine :)

Comment: Thanks again, I have published the post in question.

Answer (score 3):

> I did not find an equivalent integer type to store function pointers

That's because you can't convert function pointers to integers. Doing so results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I would not say that the standard states that converting a function pointer to an integer produces undefined behavior. See the entire C99 6.3.2.3:6, which starts “Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type”. The standard certainly does not guarantee that you can do anything useful with the result of such a conversion.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Maybe 1. it's referring to object pointers only, 2. or I am stuck with the C89 standard, but I'm sure I have recently inferred (with the help of others) that it *is* UB.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah, and I've found it! [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282032/converting-object-and-function-pointers-to-integers)

Comment: It is you, not just an homonym, right? What lead you to delete this question?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yap, it's me. Apparently, the question wasn't deemed very interesting or useful, and the only answer I've got wasn't correct and it didn't fully answer my question either; moreover, I didn't want *another* sacrificial metal question that's exposed to angry serial downvoters.

Comment: If you do not have the C99 standard handy, clause 6.3.2.3:6 continues “… If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.” It is one of the most ambiguous clauses I have ever encountered.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Indeed. As if it was saying: "the behavior may or may not be undefined". (However, I do have a copy of C99 in my Documents directory :)) Maybe it's just me and my rusty English, but I often find the wording of the standard(s) obscure (or, more precisely, overly general). Like, I would close one or two of the clauses as "too broad" if it was posted as a question here :P

Answer (score 3):

There's no such integer type for function pointers to convert.

One of the reasons is: on some machines, function addresses can be very large, bigger than any data pointers.